# Checking on multiple values in array

Tags: java, slick2d

I'm currently trying to make a small chatgame in the Slick2d framework. The framework's got a method called

```
isKeyPressed()
```

and a whole long list of variables i can use to check. For instance:

```
input.KEY_A
```

Currently the only way i can register a letter, is by having a whole list of those checkers:

```
if (input.isKeyPressed(input.KEY_A)) {
    this.text += "a";
}
if (input.isKeyPressed(input.KEY_B)) {
    this.text += "b";
}
if (input.isKeyPressed(input.KEY_C)) {
    this.text += "c";
}
```

Is there any smarter way i can do this?

I could imagine i would be able to store the input.KEYS in an array in some way, but i'm not sure if that is a proper way, and even how to implement it.

Comment: not the smarter way, but initially i would have a nested if-else rather then millions if statements .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Map<Integer,Character> keyWithLetterMap = new HashMap<Integer,Character>();
 //populates initially the map, for instance: keyWithLetterMap.put(input.KEY_A, 'a');

 for (Map.Entry<Integer, Character> keyWithLetter : keyWithLetterMap.entrySet()) {
     if(input.isKeyPressed(keyWithLetter.getKey())) 
        this.text += keyWithLetter.getValue();
 }
```

Otherwise, and even better way, use `enum` instead of `Map` ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [a HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) to store the mapping (!) - Assuming the `KEY_XX` are integers, for example, it could look like this:

```
private static final Map<Integer, String> mapping = new HashMap<Integer, String> () {{
    put(input.KEY_A, "a");
    put(input.KEY_B, "b");
    //etc
}};


for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : mapping.entrySet()) {
    if (input.isKeyPressed(entry.getKey()) this.text += entry.getValue();
}
```

The map can be made static if it is always the same so you only need to populate it once.
Note: this could be more efficient if you had an `input.getKeyPressed()` method or something similar.

Comment: A map is the way to go, but why don't you break out the nunchuks and add some java kung fu: an initializer block to bind all the puts with the declaration?

Comment: Indeed, doesn't compile! :)

Comment: Should compile now. @Bohemian Well yes I thought about it but decided to keep it simple. I've added it as a note.

Comment: That should bamboozle em enough to quiet any critics